# How do I clone a object based arraylist with its own class?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have a Class called `StockArrayList` which basically holds add, delete and update methods, I am loading a array list from a text file the array list loads into the array however in loading the array list it breaks all my methods apart from add, if it isn't loaded into array list all my methods work as expected how do i load the `StockArrayList` without breaking my methods?

```
public class StockListCLI {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
StockArrayList Stock = new StockArrayList();;
/**
 * takes a existing stockListand uses it though out the class
 * @param stock 
 */
public StockListCLI(StockArrayList stock){
    //Stock = (StockArrayList) stock; //uncomment to load stock data but it will break most of the functions below
}
```

Comment: Can you post the problem areas? I don't think there is code

Comment: that is the problem area, that one little commented line of code it basically clones the inputted StockArrayList and pass's it to Stock. My problem is this works it just seems to break the methods below which work perfectly fine it is commented out.

Comment: @Ryan There's no cloning happening in the code you showed.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a reference to Stock, that probably later will be collected by the GC. You should implement a copy constructor, override and use the `clone` (must implement `Cloneable` interface) method, or copy 1 by 1 the member variables of `stock` to `Stock`

Comment: Your (now deleted) comment about not needing `Cloneable` to use `clone()` is wrong by the way. One of the reasons to avoid `clone()`, it's really hard to get it correct.

Comment: I didn't mean for you to update your post. I meant to advise you on your wrong idea about `Cloneable`.

Comment: @Kayaman I never use `clone()`, but thanks. Anyway, Im telling OP that one of the options is to use `clone()`, so I guess he needs to know that `Cloneable` is required.

Comment: But your answer gives the impression that it's all that's required. If you do a search, you'll notice that it involves a lot more to make a correct implementation of `clone()`, so if you're not a very experienced developer, you shouldn't even bother.

Comment: @Kayaman Im not experienced with `clone()`, but it is one of the options he has to solve his problem. Im not telling him how to do it, just that he has that option.